# In postscript, how do I obtain the UnderlinePosition, which is an integer, from the currently active font?

Tags: postscript

I've tried executing the following:

```
0 UnderlinePosition rmoveto
```

This doesn't work, because UnderlinePosition is a key in the font dictionary, rather than a variable that I can access directly. I'm just trying to figure out how to obtain this value from the font dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /FontInfo is a dictionary inside each font containing the /UnderlinePosition key:

```
0
currentfont
/FontInfo get /UnderlinePostition get
rmoveto
```